# what's hops unity in network context

Tags: traceroute, nmap

I have scanned a remote server using `nmap` :

And i get the following OUTPUT :

```
 Network Distance: 22 hops
```

What's  `hops` unity?

And , is there a relationship among the others unities of distance ,such as `km` ?

Comment: What do you mean by _"unity"_?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you meant to use the word "units."

Hops are (outbound) router interfaces.  To scan to remote server, the packets you sent traveled through 22 routers before they reached the server.

Network distance is "topological" distance, and has no relationship to physical distance.  The server could be halfway around the world, or a few feet away.